# Wrong view added to scrollview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to set up this activity "ChoiceList" such that every time the save button is clicked, a new view is added to the linearLayout within the scrollView of the ChoiceList activity. The added view "choiceView" should simply be a textView contained within a frameLayout. For some reason, however, every time the save button is clicked, a new ChoiceList layout is added to the linearLayout instead of a ChoiceView. I'm an amateur android developer who is just starting to teach myself how to develop, so I have no clue where the problem lies.

Here are my java and xml files:

```
public class ChoiceList extends android.app.Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<ChoiceView> choiceList;

    private Button button;
    private LinearLayout choiceListLayout;
    private ViewGroup parentGroup;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//, List<ChoiceView> list) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        choiceList = new ArrayList<ChoiceView>();
        this.getActionBar().setTitle("");
        this.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // adds a left-facing caret alongside the app icon and enables it as an action button
                                                             // such that when the user presses it, the activity receives a call to
                                                             // onOptionsItemSelected(). The ID for the action is android.R.id.home.
        this.initLayout();
    }

    public void initLayout() {
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_choice_list); // set up initial layout
        choiceListLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceListLayout);
        parentGroup = (ViewGroup) choiceListLayout;

        button = (android.widget.Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() { // when "Save" button is clicked

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newChoiceView(); // Makes new ChoiceView with text from EditText
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Makes and displays new ChoiceView with text from EditText
     * Called within InitLayout from clicking Save button
     */
    public void newChoiceView() {
        ChoiceView cv = new ChoiceView(this.getApplicationContext());
        choiceList.add(cv); // add ChoiceView to list of ChoiceViews

        choiceListLayout.addView(cv); // display ChoiceView
    }
    ...
}
```

and the associated xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/choiceScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/choiceListLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enterChoice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/enterChoiceText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spinButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/spin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the view I'm trying to add to the scrollbar...

```
public class ChoiceView extends RelativeLayout {

    protected TextView tv;
    private String choiceString; // choice text
    private EditText et; // editText from which text comes from

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public ChoiceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater choiceViewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View choiceView = choiceViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_view, this, true);

        LayoutInflater choiceListInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View choiceList = choiceListInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_choice_list, this, true);

        et = (EditText) choiceList.findViewById(R.id.enterChoice); // finds EditText from which string heeds
        tv = (TextView) choiceView.findViewById(R.id.choiceViewTextView); // finds TextView to display text
        tv.setText(et.getText().toString());

        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

and its associated xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/whatever" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choiceViewTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/spin"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: why are you inflating a choiceList layout in your ChoiceView class?

Comment: To be honest, I added an inflator for the ChoiceList layout in the ChoiceView class because someone told me that I needed to in order to get the editText information. Was that a bad tip?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Yes, because when you inflate it, it renders an entirely new choicelist layout, which is completely separate from the original choicelist. This is why you're getting problems.

Nonetheless you should probably use a ListView like the other guy said, since it is more optimized. Although there are some circumstances where you might want to do it this way.

Comment: That makes sense. But without inflating the layout, how do I find the EditText id? If I get rid of the ChoiceList layout inflater, my EditText becomes null (see my previous forum question).

Comment: Modify the constructor of ChoiceView to take an EditText as an argument. Then, in ChoiceList class, use `EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterChoice);` and pass that to any choiceview when you create one.

Comment: Holy crap you just blew my mind. It's so simple. I can't believe I didn't consider that before. Hah. Well thanks a bunch :D !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically add elements to a scrollable list which can then later be selected.

Android already provides a UI component to do this, the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), which is backed by an adapter which bridges your model (i.e. data) with the UI.  In this case your model is a list of strings.  The adapter is responsible for creating the views (in this case TextViews) as they are required.  [Check out this excellent tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually knew that ListView exists, I guess I just thought it was superfluous to have to add an adapter and all that, so I tried to just hard code it into the main classes.

I'll change this to a ListView since it seems like that would be the idillic way to do this, but out of curiosity, do you where my code went wrong? It seems to me that it should still be doable using a ScrollView.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I think you got an answer above though, right?  Anyway, ListView + Adapter is the right way to go as Android will automatically re-use the layout to save overhead in inflation / object creation.  Just make sure to check and see if the "covertView" of your adapter's getView method is not null and if so, use that instead of inflate one yourself.  You can get (virtually) unlimited number of rows using this method.